# Separating the concerns in Android-Java

Tags: java, javascript, android

I don't want to hard-code my `URL` and `API` methods in my application. I was doing something like this in my `JavaScript` Application. How do I do the same in `Java`? This is the `Revealing Module Pattern`.

```
var settings = (function() {
     var settings = {
         'URL': '',
         'login': 'something',
         'password': 'something'
     };

     return {
        getSettings: function(name) { return settings[name]; },
    };
})();
```

I would then use this to make my REST communication, something like this way:

```
var url = settings.getSettings('URL');
```

How would I proceed the same with a Java class? Any article or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @njzk2: Well i have tried the encapsuling and accessing it via getter and setters.

Comment: i don't understand where are you stuck ?

Comment: @njzk2: Well i don't want to hard-code my URL and settings array across the application and i want to make it generic.

Comment: yes, and so ? what have you tried ? have you written any java code yet ?

Comment: @njzk2: Nope... i was looking through the docs... and not yet done anything code wise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string resources store to hold any string (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#Strings), so you could place the information there.

Hopefully you're aware that having the password in plain text will make it susceptible to be copied or easily modified, so you should look at encryption and digital signatures to ensure that it doesn't get easily discovered and that it is the URL, username, and password that you enter.

Comment: That was my thought initially, but it would lead to security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the values from a properties file.[javadoc for java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)
A very common way to use this class is to store the properties in a file, and call the `load` method to read them from that file.  In this case, the `Properties` instance would take the place of the `settings` class you used in your JavaScript example.